# Map list of text to their letter-counts in unison

Tags: unison-lang

I wonder why

```
use .base
use .List

> foo = ["abc", "abcdef", "a", "zzz"]

> map (x -> size x) foo
```

The last row errors. Ucm says:

```
  I'm not sure what size means at line 5, columns 13-17

     5 | > map (x -> size x) foo

  Whatever it is, it has a type that conforms to a ->{} b.
  I found some terms in scope that have matching names and types. Maybe you meant one of these:

    - .base.Bytes.size : base.Bytes -> base.Nat
    - .base.Heap.size : base.Heap k v -> base.Nat
    - .base.List.Nonempty.size : base.List.Nonempty a -> base.Nat
    - .base.List.size : [a] -> base.Nat
    - .base.Map.size : base.Map k v -> base.Nat
    - .base.Set.size : base.Set k -> base.Nat
    - .base.Text.size : base.Text -> base.Nat
```

It's the bottom one I'm aiming for in the mapping function.

I've tried:

```
> map (x -> size "foobar") foo

> size "johndoe"
```

And both of those give me what I would [expect.](https://www.unisonweb.org/docs/language-reference)

Comment: The tag [tag:unison] is meant for the synchronization program. There is no tag for the unison language. Maybe make a [tag:unison-lang] tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unison is confused somehow and you need to qualify which size-function you want by doing:

```
map (x -> Text.size x) b
```